# OS X Safari HTML select visual artifact when zoomed in?

Tags: html, safari

First off, I know this is an extremely narrow edge case, but in the interest of due diligence with a client, I have to ask. Consider everyone's favorite no-frills HTML tutorial site, W3Schools.com, specifically their demo page on HTML select boxes: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select2

Open that page up in Safari on OS X (may exist in Windows, but honestly, who uses Safari for Windows?) and zoom in four times. Open up the select box. See where the normal check mark has changed to two dots?

[image: select with two dots instead of a check mark]

I'm perfectly content to call that a Safari bug and close it as cantfix. Googling "safari html select two dots" doesn't get me anywhere. Is this fixable?

Comment: This is not about programming, so it is off-topic for SO.  Maybe on [webmasters.se] or [apple.se]

Comment: That was actually the question - whether it was something that could be fixed in the programming or not.

Comment: I hate to be a "me too" guy but did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Nope. We just told our qa group that no one zoomed in to 800% and we weren't going to spend time trying to fix it.

Comment: It appears to be directly related to the `font-size` property. Changing `font-size` to `20px` fixes the checkmark, but at `21px` it turns into the dots. It's almost as if the checkmark can no longer fit in the space provided for it and the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)  property is set to `ellipsis` so it is turning the checkmark into an ellipsis. Setting `text-overflow` to `clip` does not fix this. [Also see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707365/two-dots-instead-of-checkmark-in-safari-select-options).

Comment: Good explanation - that makes sense, all things considered.