# Two dots instead of checkmark in Safari select options

Tags: css, safari

Rather than a check, Safari seems to add two dots in front of the selected option in a drop down if the font is larger. `-webkit-appearance: none` doesn't seem to get rid of this.  Any ideas how to get around this programatically?  Is this just a bug in Safari itself?

e.g. http://jsbin.com/guzukepoto/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Hm, and other browsers are supposed to show a check mark? How exactly?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? It appears to be directly related to the `font-size` property. Changing `font-size` to `20px` fixes the checkmark, but at `21px` it turns into the dots. It's almost as if the checkmark can no longer fit in the space provided for it and the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)  property is set to `ellipsis` so it is turning the checkmark into an ellipsis. Setting `text-overflow` to `clip` does not fix this.

Comment: I've not yet found an answer:(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this bug was fixed in Safari 9, but broken in Safari 8 (and maybe earlier).  In Safari 9, if the font is increased a lot (e.g. to 50px http://jsbin.com/xoduzizita/2/edit?html,output), the checkmark appears cutoff, but is much better than two dots!