# Safari Select-Popup rendered with truncated check

Tags: html, css, safari

When I increase the `font-size` of an `<select> <input>` with `appearance: none;` Safari also increases the `font-size` of the popup options, which leads to a truncated check sign. How can I fix this?

[**Live example**](http://codepen.io/rolandschuetz/pen/meKZNr)

[image: safari rendering bug]

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: Safari version? Retina? Looks OK in Safari 9.0.1 (Retina).

Comment: In my OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 with Safari 9.0.1 on Retina it does not look correct, I have the two dots instead of a checkbox.

Comment: Can't reproduce on OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 (tried different screen resolutions and zoom-in/zoom-out).

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707365/two-dots-instead-of-checkmark-in-safari-select-options

Comment: Version, Retina and OS? Very older versions (tested on 5.1.7) shows a traditional dropdown without any issue. And never versions (tested on 9.0.1) shows it fine as well. Must be a bug with versions during the transition period from traditional dropdown to popup layout.

Answer (score 1):

We noticed a strange difference based on OSX version.

I have `El Capitan` with Safari `9.0.3` and do NOT see the ellipsis. But my co-worker had Yosemitie with the same version of Safari `9.0.3` and he DID see the ellipsis. So the bug seems possibly related to the OS/Safari combo and not just the browser version.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Safari. It was fixed in version 9, but broken in Safari 8 (and maybe earlier). I've checked in Safaru 9.0.1 - looks fine.

Comment: I still get the same error in Safari 9.0.1 https://youtu.be/98bTPyiddMk
Any ideas for fixes?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it's impossible to fix by css. It's not reproduced in my Safari 9.0.1. You can try to make select  element bigger (increase width), maybe it will help.

Comment: I tried, didn't help sadly.Ok, then I have to live with that bug.